# React native Migration to 61: Metro bundler is up on the ios device but does not running

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, mobile-development, metro-bundler

I am trying to understand how does the Metro Bundler works.
While migrating to 61 I faced the issue of no bundler started on IOS, after adding start packager script manually as a build phase to Xcode the metro bundler is up for both the emulator and the device, but the green line with percents is running only when installing the app on the emulator when installing on the device it is stack after "Loading dependency graph done" however the app is installed properly on the device and running. Please help me to understand what is the difference between build process on device and emulator. Thank you